# How can I get a GPS location data from google?

Tags: java, android, gps

Me and my team are new  to android development. We have been assigned to do an assignment on any field we want and we have chose to develop an android app that helps find the nearest hospital location in an emergency situation. For this I need to get access to google map data. Is this feasible or there is a better process?

Comment: this has an answer here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Thank you this might help me... @OusmaneMahyDiaw

Answer (score 0):

You can look at **GoogleApiClient** / latest Google play location services. Android has location services inbuilt too (a location manager and listener with different event methods)